# How do I access Awesomefonts in Qt on OpenSuse

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, font-awesome, qicon

I wish to use some of the icons in fontawesome (http://fontawesome.io/icons) in my Qt Application, I have extracted the fontawesome-webfont.ttf file into usr/share/fonts.I tried searching online but could n't find any such examples.This is a sample code I have written for extracting an image out of a Resource(not what is required) and also accessing some Qfonts that were existent in Qfont library itself.( i.e courier new in the example below).

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    gridLayout = new QGridLayout( centralWidget );
    mylabel = new QLabel();
    mylabel2= new QLabel();

    font = new QFont("courier");
    addresspic = new QPixmap(":/new/prefix1/address.png");
    *addresspic=addresspic->scaled(50,50,Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation);
    mylabel->setPixmap(*addresspic);

    mylabel2->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
    mylabel2->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(100,100),QSize(150, 150)));
    mylabel2->setText("  ADDRESS ICON ");
    gridLayout->addWidget(mylabel2);
    gridLayout->addWidget(mylabel);
    font->setItalic(true);
    font->setPixelSize(20);
    mylabel2->setFont(*font);


//   gridLayout->setVerticalSpacing(1);
//   gridLayout->setHorizontalSpacing(1);

    this->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Thanks again

EDIT: The screenshot of error [image]

EDIT 2: Trying G.M.'s method resulted in the following error : Any Idea why? 
 [image]

Comment: try with: font = new QFont("fontawesome-webfont");

Comment: @eyllanesc It doesnt work, how does qt know where to access the icon from

Comment: Did you update the font cache after copying the files? That would be `sudo fc-cache -fv`.

Comment: @Matteo Italia tried that as well

Comment: @theindianphil1 change to: virtual void paint(QPainter * painter, const QRect& rect, QIcon::Mode mode, QIcon::State state)Q_DECL_OVERRIDE ;
    virtual QPixmap pixmap(const QSize &size, QIcon::Mode mode, QIcon::State state)Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

Comment: @theindianphil1 Removes the semicolon before Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

Comment: @eyllanesc same error , plus declaration error also

Comment: @theindianphil1 remove Q_DECL_OVERRIDE

Comment: @eyllanesc did the above, null ptr error shows up along with iterator issues..screenshot attached

Comment: @theindianphil1 add QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++14 to Project2.pro

Comment: @eyllanesc another error:  unrecognized command line option '-std=gnu++14'

Comment: @theindianphil1 try with: add CONFIG += c++11 to Project2.pro

Comment: @eyllanesc : same error as screenshot :/

Comment: @theindianphil1 change Q_NULLPTR to 0

Comment: @eyllanesc Boss, thank you so much for the guidance, The code worked, it still shows some "issues" but program runs as expected.Could you guide me with respect to QfonDatabase if possible as well? Once again , Lots of thanks

Comment: @eyllanesc how do we go about resizing the icon ,if needed?

Comment: @theindianphil1 http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#iconSize-prop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://github.com/dridk/QFontIcon download and add the `qfonticon.h` and `qfonticon.cpp` files to your project, then create the icons with the following code:

```
QFontIcon::addFont("/path/your/fonts/{your font}.ttf");
QIcon icon = QFontIcon::icon(0xf2b9);

{your widget}->setIcon(icon);
```

Example:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QPushButton>
#include "qfonticon.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QWidget *centralWidget;
    QGridLayout *gridLayout;

    centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    gridLayout = new QGridLayout( centralWidget );

    QFontIcon::addFont("/usr/share/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");


    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        QIcon icon = QFontIcon::icon(0xf2b9+i);
        QPushButton *b = new QPushButton();
        b->setIcon(icon);
        gridLayout->addWidget(b);
    }
    this->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

[image]

**More Information**: https://github.com/dridk/QFontIcon

I tested it with Qt 5.7 and Qtcreator 4.2

Comment: Lot of errors are showing up :
'Q_DECL_OVERRIDE' does not name a type
     virtual void paint(QPainter * painter, const QRect& rect, QIcon::Mode mode, QIcon::State state)Q_DECL_OVERRIDE ;


                        /home/adt/Project/Project1/Project2/MainWindow.cpp:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Ui::MainWindow'
     ui(new Ui::MainWindow)


                ^                                                                            ^

Comment: @theindianphil1 qt4 or qt5?

Comment: qt 5.3.2 using qt creator 3.2.1

Comment: This one error only :

: error: 'Q_DECL_OVERRIDE' does not name a type
     virtual void paint(QPainter * painter, const QRect& rect, QIcon::Mode mode, QIcon::State state);Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
                                                                                                     ^

Comment: @theindianphil1 
I tested it with Qt 5.7 and Qtcreator 4.2

Comment: is there any other way, like directly accessing it from the system directory? using unicodes or sort?

Comment: how to change the color option for an icon? Tried using :

        QIcon icon = QFontIcon::icon(0xf2e0,QColor(1,0,1,255));
Still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the font explicitly with...

```
int fid = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("/usr/share/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
```

You can then query the font family name(s) using...

```
QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(fid);
```

In my case the above resulted in the single family name "FontAwesome".  That being the case you should then be able to use the font with...

```
QFont f("FontAwesome");
```

**Note**: The above seems to work as far as it goes but specifying a point size for the font isn't working as expected. Not sure why as the ttf file appears to contain the requested glyph sizes.

**Edit 1**
The `QFont` as constructed above can be used like any other unicode font.  So a `QLabel` could be created with...

```
QLabel label;
label.setFont(QFont("FontAwesome"));
label.setText("\uf0fe");    /* f0fe is the code point for fa-plus-square */
```

Note that the answer provided by @eyllanesc is probably a far better approach.  I'm simply adding this edit for completeness sake.

Comment: How do you access the icons individually inside fontawesome-webfont.ttf,also can you share your code

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but the output is garbage values. I have edited the question so that you can see the output.Any advice what went wrong?

Comment: You're using `QFont("FontAwesome")` in both `QLabel`s in your code but the "ADDRESS ICON" text is being displayed as it would for a standard font.  That suggests the font isn't being loaded correctly.  Check the value being returned from `QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont` -- If it's -1 there's a problem.

Comment: its returning ("FontAwesome")  itself, corrected code as well, only one of the labels use FontAwesome. Still producing Garbage Values.Updated ScreenShot

Comment: Hey, the code you shared in the Edit works.One more small thing, how do i change the colour of these icons to any other colour from the standard colour.